# Getting the rate of change of a rectangle's base if its top-right corner is defined as $y = 2^x$

Tags: calculus

> Have some rectangle. The bottom-left corner of the rectangle is at the
>   origin point. The top-right corner is part of a curve defined by the
>   function $y = 2^x$. This top-right corner goes up at a rate of $1$
>   unit per second. At what speed is the rectangle's area growing when $x = 2$?

Well, since the top-right vertex is growing by one unit per second, we have that

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = 1$$

When $x = 2$, we have that $y = 4$. The area of the rectangle right now is $8$.

The rectangle's area is defined as

$$A = x \cdot y$$

The derivative is

$$\frac{dA}{dt} = \frac{dx}{dt}\cdot y + \frac{dy}{dt} \cdot x$$

Plug in our data:

$$\frac{dA}{dt} = \frac{dx}{dt}\cdot 4 + 1 \cdot 2$$

Oh. We are missing one thing: the rate of change of $x$.

But how do I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: We have 
$$y=2^x=\exp(x\ln 2).\tag{1}$$ 
You know $\frac{dy}{dt}$. Now use Equation 1 to find $\frac{dx}{dt}$. The Chain Rule will be useful.

Comment: Hmm... So $$y = e^{x \cdot \ln(2)}$$ If I want to know the rate of change of $x$ I would need... the derivative, I guess. Which is $$\frac{dy}{dt} = e^{x \cdot \ln(2)}\cdot \ln(2) \cdot \frac{dx}{dt}$$ Since $\frac{dy}{dt} = 1$ I can have that $$1 = e^{x\cdot \ln(2)}\cdot \ln(2) \cdot \frac{dx}{dt} \implies  \frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{\frac{1}{\ln(2)}}{e^{x\cdot \ln(2)}}$$ Then replace $x = 2$ and we get that $$\frac{dx}{dt} = 0.36$$This seems to lead me to the correct answer according to the book. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. You may already without the $\exp$ stuff that the derivative of $2^x$ with respect to $x$ is $(\ln 2)2^x$. If so we get $\frac{dy}{dt}=(\ln 2)2^x\frac{dx}{dt}$. Now "freeze" at $x=2$ to find $\frac{dx}{dt}$ at the instant when $x=2$.

Comment: You... you should've said that instead!

Comment: Not everybody knows the formula for the derivative of $a^x$, so the answer had that calculation built in.